# Form is sending data to server when onsubmit should be returning false

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate a form. I want it to work whether Javascript is enabled or not. If javascript is enabled, I want validation to happen client side first. I have my onsubmit calling my function validateContactForm() but even though false should be being returned, nothing the form details are just be sent.

I have tried various ways of calling the validatContactForm method including:

```
onsubmit="validateContactForm();"

onsubmit="validateContactForm()"
```

and

```
onsubmit="return validateContactForm()"
```

and I'm not quite sure which  I should be using and why. Should I include the semi-colon? Does it matter? Should a false being returned by onsubmit prevent the form being submitted?

I have read that the onsubmit event is bypassed if the submit() method is called by javascript, but I am just using the plain old submit button method.

Here's my html:

```
<form method="POST" action="email_processing.php" onsubmit="validateContactForm();">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Company Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" />
        <br />
        <label>Contact Name: * </label>
        <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" />
        <br />
        <label>Phone Number: </label>
        <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" />
        <br />
        <label>Email: * </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        <br />
        <label>Enquiry: </label>
        <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and the javascript:

```
function validateEmail(elementValue){
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    if(!emailPattern.test(elementValue) || !validateString(elementValue)) {
        alert("In false valEmail");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function validateContactName(elemValue) {
    if($.trim(elemValue) == "" || !validateString($.trim(elemValue))) {
        alert("In false valContactName");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function validateString(elemValue) {
    // Protect against malicious javascript
    if(elemValue.match(/[<>!]+/) != null) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function validateContactForm() {
    alert("Here");
    var email = $.trim($('#email').val());
    if(!validateEmail(email)) {
        alert(email + = ' is an invalid email address');
        $('#email').focus();
        $('#email').select();
        alert("In valConForm email false");
        return false;
    }
    if(!validateString($('#contact_name').val())) {
        alert('Please enter a contact name.');
        $('#contact_name').focus();
        $('#contact_name').select();
        alert("In valContForm contname false");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Definitely be grateful to know why onsubmit doesn't seem to be being called (none of the alerts are being fired off). And also be interested to know if this is the right way to be going about this. Please not that I feel that I can't fire off the POST request by a jquery ajax call just in case someone has javascript disabled.

Thanks very much

Joe

Answer (score 2):

change to:

```
onsubmit="return validateContactForm();"
```

Also, if an error occurs in your validation script the onsubmit WILL fire. Add try/catch to see if you have any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
onsubmit="return validateContactForm();"
```

or on submit button

```
onclick="return validateContactForm();"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi insted of Submit button use simple HTML button

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="validateContactForm();"/>
```

and in javaScript use

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. I appreciate it.

I had a syntax error in my validateContactForm() method:

```
alert(email + = ' is an invalid email address');
```

There is a space between the + and the =

I really don't understand what the alerts previous to that weren't working, though. :(